# HAPROXY - redirect URL and keep the same URI

Tags: load-balancing, redirect, rewrite, haproxy, redirection

Im using haproxy to do redirections. Basically I have a URL ( https://**google**.com/*/* ) and I want to keep the same URI and just redirect only the base url ( https://**test**.com/*/*). For HAPROXY it has to be irrelevant whatever comes after the base url will stay the same, only the base url needs to be changed.

Thankyou